# iText + RPC. How send PDF from Server to Client

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, itext, rpc

i'm new in GAE + GWT. I see that the new iText version 5.2.1 work in Android and GAE. I dont know how to send the PDF from server to the client using RPC service. Anyone knows a wey?

Answer (score 0):

A PDF is just another collection of bytes. Here is a link with some examples.

http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/11b749d50221499e

Answer (score 0):

RPC is an ajax request  to server.  You need standard request which could return byte array as a stream to client.  In gwt I’ve used RequestBuilder at client side comunicating with  Jersey web service at server side.